# When reading a WAV file, dataID is printed as "fact" and not "data"

Tags: audio, wav

I'm new to audio playback and have spent the day reading over the wav file specification.  I wrote a simple program to extract the header of a file but right now my program always returns false as the DataID keeps returning as "fact" instead of "data".

There are a few reasons I believe this could be happening.

- The file I am reading in has a format size of 18, whereas [this resource](https://web.archive.org/web/20141213140451/https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) states a valid PCM file should have a format size of 16.
- The format code of the file I am reading is 6, meaning it has probably been compressed.
- The value of dataSize is far too small (only 4). Even though the file has 30 seconds of playback when ran through VLC or Windows Media Player.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
using (var reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(wavFile, FileMode.Open)))
{
    // Read all descriptor info into variables to be passed
    // to an ASWAVFile instance.
    var chunkID       = reader.ReadBytes(4); // Should contain "RIFF"
    var chunkSize     = reader.ReadBytes(4);
    var format        = reader.ReadBytes(4); // Should contain "WAVE"

    var formatID      = reader.ReadBytes(4); // Should contain "fmt"
    var formatSize    = reader.ReadBytes(4); // 16 for PCM format.
    var formatCode    = reader.ReadBytes(2); // Determines linear quantization - 1 = PCM, else it has been compressed
    var channels      = reader.ReadBytes(2); // mono = 1, stereo = 2
    var sampleRate    = reader.ReadBytes(4); // 8000, 44,100 etc
    var byteRate      = reader.ReadBytes(4); // SampleRate * Channels * BitsPerSample / 8
    var blockAlign    = reader.ReadBytes(2); // Channels * BitsPerSample / 8
    var bitsPerSample = reader.ReadBytes(2); // If mono 8, if stereo 16 etc.

    var padding = byteToInt(formatSize);

    // Read any extra values so we can jump to the data chunk - extra padding should only be set here
    // if formatSize is 18
    byte[] fmtExtraSize = new byte[2];

    if (padding == 18)
    {
        fmtExtraSize = reader.ReadBytes(2);
    }


    // Read the final header information in, we can then set
    // other 
    var dataID   = reader.ReadBytes(4);      // Should contain "data"
    var dataSize = reader.ReadBytes(4);      // Calculated by Samples * Channels * BitsPerSample / 8

    // Check if the file is in the correct format
    if ( 
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(chunkID)  != "RIFF" ||
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(format)   != "WAVE" ||
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(formatID) != "fmt"  ||
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(dataID)   != "data"
        )
    {
        return false;
    }


    //file = new ASWAVFile();
}
```

If I dump the values of chunkID, format, formatID and dataID I get:

```
RIFF, WAVE, fmt, fact
```

Causing the method to return false.   Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RIFF specification doesn't require the 'data' chunk to follow the 'fmt' chunk. You may see some files that write a 'pad' chunk after the 'fmt' chunk to ensure page alignment for better streaming.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV

Also the format code indicates the audio compression type, as you noted. Valid format codes are in mmreg.h (on Windows): (Format 6 is aLaw, indeed a compression type).

http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/documents/audioformats/wave/Docs/MMREG.H

Your best bet is to write code that reads chunk headers, checks for the type you want, and skip past it to the next chunk if you can't find what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ron, I just printed out the header and saw I have fact, followed by data.  Is there a limit to the amount of padding that can be set?  Or could you recommend any further resources that may help me solve this issue

Comment: See updated answer. There really isn't a limit to the padding. The safest bet is to ready the header bytes, look at the tag and if isn't what you want do a file seek to the end of the chunk.

Comment: Thanks Ron, appreciate your help.  That should be more than enough to solve the issue.